# How do I use the sx prop in material UI to implement styling only when the component is selected?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, frontend

As shown in the code below,I have configured useState such that when a ListItem is clicked on, selected is true. When I want to do is implement specific styling when the item is selected. I would like to do this in the sx prop and not used a styled component as that would be unnecesarry for such simple styling. What I want to have is that when a ListItem is selected, the ListItemText turns blue and the ListItem turn a lighter shade of blue.

```js
import { useState } from 'react'
import { Box, Drawer, CssBaseline, AppBar, Toolbar, Avatar, List } from '@mui/material';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import ListItem from '@mui/material/ListItem';
import ListItemButton from '@mui/material/ListItemButton';
import ListItemIcon from '@mui/material/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@mui/material/ListItemText';
import HomeOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/HomeOutlined"
import PeopleOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/PeopleOutlined"
import PersonOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/PersonOutlined"
import CalendarTodayOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/CalendarTodayOutlined';
import HelpOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/HelpOutlined"
import PieChartOutlineOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/PieChartOutlineOutlined"
import TimelineOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/TimelineOutlined"
import FolderSharedOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/FolderSharedOutlined';
import { Link as RouterLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useTheme } from '@mui/material'
import { ColorModeContext, tokens } from "./../theme"
import { useContext } from 'react';
import Logo from "./../assets/code2.jpg"

const SideBar = () => {
    const theme = useTheme();
    const colorMode = useContext(ColorModeContext);
    const colors = tokens(theme.palette.mode);
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState("Dashboard")

    const handleListItemClick = (text) => {
        setSelected(text)
    }

    const Item = ({ icon, text, to, selected }) => {
        console.log(selected === text);
        return (
            <ListItem key={text}
                selected={selected === text}
                disablePadding
                onClick={() => handleListItemClick(text)}
                sx={{
                    "&$selected": {
                        "& .MuiListItem.Mui-selected": {
                            backgroundColor: "blue",
                        }
                    },
                    "&$selected:hover": {
                        backgroundColor: "white",
                        '& .MuiListItem-root': {
                            color: "white"
                        }
                    }
                }}>
                <ListItemButton component={RouterLink} to={to}>
                    <ListItemIcon>
                        {icon}
                    </ListItemIcon>
                    <ListItemText selected={selected === text} primary={text}
                        sx={{
                            "&$selected": {
                                "& .MuiListItemText.Mui-selected": {
                                    color: "blue",
                                }
                            }}}                    />
                </ListItemButton>
            </ListItem>)
    }

    return (
        <Drawer sx={{
            width: 240,
            flexShrink: 0,
            '& .MuiDrawer-paper': {
                p: 2,
                width: 240,
                boxSizing: 'border-box',
                backgroundColor: `${colors.primary[500]}`,
            }
        }} variant="permanent" anchor="left">
            <Box textAlign="center" m="0 0 15px 0">
                <Typography variant="h3" color={colors.grey[100]} fontWeight="bold" sx={{ m: "10px 0 0 0" }}> ADMINIS</Typography>
            </Box>
            <Box mb="10px">
                <Box display="flex" justifyContent="center" alignItems="center">
                    <Avatar alt="logo" src={Logo} sx={{ width: 100, height: 100, cursor: "pointer"}} />
                </Box>
            </Box>
            <Box textAlign="center">
                <Typography variant="h2" color={colors.grey[100]} fontWeight="bold" sx={{ m: "10px 0 0 0" }}> Huvon Goodridge</Typography>
                <Typography variant="h5" color={colors.greenAccent[500]}>VP Fancy Admin</Typography>
            </Box>
            <List>
                <Item selected={selected} icon={<HomeOutlinedIcon />} text={"Dashboard"} to={'dashboard'} />
            </List>
            <Typography variant="h6" color={colors.grey[300]} sx={{ m: "15px 0px 0px 5px" }}>
                Data
            </Typography>
            <List>
                <Item selected={selected} icon={<PeopleOutlinedIcon />} text={"Team"} to={'team'} />
                <Item selected={selected} icon={<FolderSharedOutlinedIcon />} text={"Projects"} to={"projects"} />
            </List>
            <Typography variant="h6" color={colors.grey[300]} sx={{ m: "15px 0px 0px 5px" }}>
                Pages
            </Typography>
            <List>
                <Item selected={selected} icon={<PersonOutlinedIcon />} text={"Profile"} to={'profile'} />
                <Item selected={selected} icon={<CalendarTodayOutlinedIcon />} text={"Calendar"} to={'calendar'} />
                <Item selected={selected} icon={<HelpOutlinedIcon />} text={"FAQ"} to={'faq'} />
            </List>
            <Typography variant="h6" color={colors.grey[300]} sx={{ m: "15px 0px 0px 5px" }}>
                Charts
            </Typography>
            <List>
                <Item selected={selected} icon={<PieChartOutlineOutlinedIcon />} text={"Pie Chart"} to={'piechart'} />
                <Item selected={selected} icon={<TimelineOutlinedIcon />} text={"Timeline"} to={'timeline'} />
            </List>
        </Drawer>)
}

export default SideBar;
```

I have tried multiple ways to select the classes of the components that I want but to no avail. I expected this to change the backgroundColor but it did not and furthermore, it failed to change the text color. I have looked at the documentation on material ui website for this but it did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using `sx` prop to style the selected component, perhaps try add styles to `&.Mui-selected` and `&.Mui-selected:hover` property names.

Example: (with an over simplified live demo on: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yzah7p?file=src/App.js))

```
<ListItemButton
  sx={{
    "&.Mui-selected": { backgroundColor: "hotpink", color: "#fff" },
    "&.Mui-selected:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "hotpink",
    },
  }}
></ListItemButton>
```

Comment: John Li, thank you so much. This was so annoying because there are spaces in the documentation between the "&" and the "." Its good knowing that it was so simple.

Comment: @LordEscanor Did it work? The example with a space after `&` is probably for setting the style on the parent `List`, which could also be tried. Anyways hope this will help! If it does, please consider choose to accept the answer so this post is complete. Thanks.